# Системное намерение на новые сутки

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver

Необходимо сделать приёмник Broadcast, который будет реагировать или на начало новых суток, или на время 00:00, однако я не могу найти устраивающее этим критериям системного намерения. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, на данный момент вы не можете запланировать работу на определенное время. Если у вас есть критичная по времени реализация, вам следует использовать AlarmManager для установки сигнала тревоги, который может срабатывать во время Doze Mode, используя [setAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) или [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Создание класса *Worker*:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
    @Override
    public Worker.WorkerResult doWork() {
        // Здесь вы будете выполнять вашу задачу
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Вы можете запланировать *OneTimeWorkRequest* как на примере:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest mywork=
        new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
        .setInitialDelay(<duration>, <TimeUnit>)// Use this when you want to add initial delay or schedule initial work to `OneTimeWorkRequest` e.g. setInitialDelay(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mywork);
```

Вы можете задать дополнительные настройки:

// Create a Constraints that defines when the task should run

```
Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
    .setRequiresCharging(true)
    // Constraints.Builder Здесь есть много других настроек
     .build();
```

И создать *OneTimeWorkRequest*, используя заданные настройки:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest mywork=
                new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
     .setConstraints(myConstraints)
     .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mywork);
```

Вы можете задавать периодичность ваших задач:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                                   .build();
  WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWork);
```